# Sign a jira rest request with RSA-SHA1 on browser via pure js

Tags: javascript, rest, oauth, rsa, jira

I am developing a tool to create jira issue on my behalf. So far i have been able to generate a access token and access token secret.

But now, when actually firing the jira rest api from browser, i am using [jsrsasign](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign) for creating `authorization` header.

As per the examples given in repository, i am doing this:

```
  var rsa = new RSAKey();
  rsa.readPrivateKeyFromPEMString(<MY_PRIVATE_KEY>);
  var hSig = rsa.signString(<THE_MESSAGE>, "sha1");
  var base64_encoded_signature = hex2b64(hSig);
```

My question is, what should be `THE_MESSAGE` and how should i generate it?

EDIT : I tried the `SIGNATURE_STRING` in place of `THE_MESSAGE`. The i got the error, `singature length found 96, but expected to be 64`.

I tried all the relavent api's shared by lib shown [here](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/RSAKey.html). But each time i got the same error.

Comment: Where do you get MY_PRIVATE_KEY from? The combination of browser and private key sounds suspicious to me.

Comment: Well, i generated MY_PRIVATE_KEY via openssl (commanline).. I am just using this key into my js code, as a stringified form.

Comment: This way you share your private key with the whole world!

Comment: Well, that is not the issue in the particular scenario.

Comment: @codeofnode have you found a solution for this one? Are you using OAuth for authentication ? I have posted a question similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193587/how-to-create-oauthv1-rsa-sha1-postman-authorization-request-header-with-axios. maybe you could take a look. thanks